# ARM Hard Float ABI Removal

Tags: c++, gcc, android-ndk, llvm-clang

It seems that the "hard float" options of the NDK have been [removed from the latest version of the Android NDK](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/HardFloatAbi.md)

The page lists three reasons for the removal

1. People often use it because they think it's required to get floating point instructions, which is incorrect.
2. Most of the cases where people do see a performance improvement here are likely bugs/missed optimizations in either the compiler or the user‘s code, and hiding those means they won’t get fixed.
3. It‘s full of bugs and fixing them and keeping them fixed isn’t worth the benefit, especially in a world where you can avoid the problem entirely by making your app 64-bit.

The third point interests me. Does that mean that if I compile using the arm64-v8a architecture then the whole "hard float" business becomes a non-issue, and my code compiles as if it was on?

I'm really just interested in getting as much floating point processing power as possible, I don't care about supporting more than a few specific devices that I know can handle it.

I'm fine with rolling back to r10e, but I'd like to know if I can use the arm64-v8a architecture and not worry about the hard/soft float stuff. [This article on the debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort/VfpComparison) scared me into wanting hard float on, but at this point I'm fairly out of my depth and feel the need for some expert input.

Thanks for any info you can provide,

- John

Comment: fyi The log says the doc was written 1 year and 2 months ago - so it's probably been gone for a while

Comment: fyi Removed in NDK-r12 (current is r15)  https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ndk-r12-release/CHANGELOG.md  so r13 will probably be ok for you.  NDK archives: https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases.html

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'll try out the releases around that time and see what happens.